# blink only div not inner html

Tags: html, css, animation, opacity

Blinking only div not the inner html / text in pure CSS

Below code blinks everything:

```css
.blinking {
  animation: opacity 2s ease-in-out infinite;
  opacity: 1;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #0092dc;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 30%;
}

@keyframes opacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="blinking blue">Researching...
  <div class="red">hi</div>
</div>
```

Blinking only div not the inner html / text in pure CSS

Blinking only div not the inner html / text in pure CSS

Comment: Do you want the animation to affect only the background, but not the text?

Comment: yes, only the background (blue color), any text or red color background should **not** animate / blink. @s.kuznetsov